# Can use profile in maven release plugin preparationGoals?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a project in which I make configuration for using `maven-release-plugin`.
Configration is like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
       <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
       <useReleaseProfile>true</useReleaseProfile>
       <releaseProfiles>profile1,profile2</releaseProfiles>
       <preparationGoals>
           clean verify -Pprofile3,profile4
       </preparationGoals>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The problem is that I am using profile in preparationGoals but I keep getting error on build.
The error is like this:

```
[INFO] [ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "profile4". 
You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. 
Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.
```

As you can see I use version 2.5.3 of maven-release-plugin.
I used to used version 2.2.2 of maven-release-plugin and it worked just fine.

With maven-release-plugin:2.5.3 when I call `mvn clean verify -Pprofile3,profile4` from command line it works just fine.

Comment: Why do you need to activate profiles for running a release?

Comment: I have something to do on preparation for release time.

Comment: That was obvious but you haven't answered that..what are you doing there in particular ? I think if you need to do such things most of the times there is something wrong...

Comment: The exact work is that I have some db script files that I want to compact them into a convert file. I have developed a plugin which do it for me. I can do it through perform of release but my plugin commit some thing which should be commit on trunk not on tag. So it is the complete matter.

Comment: First a plugin which commits things is the wrong way. A plugin should never change the source in any way. If you package them you compact them and add them to your project as supplemental package (zip/..)...

Comment: Is there any rules against it? As far as I know release plugin change sources and commit sources  not one time but two time. Why other plugin shouldn't?

Comment: But it only changes the pom file which is changed based on the version number nothing else...The plugin should generate things from it and put the into correct location so the will be packaged into the resulting jar/war etc. apart from that I can't really understand what kind of changes you are making ..but it sounds you are not following the build life cycle with your plugin which causes issues at the moment...

Comment: I have some db scripts for convert. I make them packed into a convert file. That is why I wrote the plugin. I think you are right about me not following the build life cycle, But I don't know what other choices I may have. Maybe I should change my point of view to my problem. Tanx any way.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to use the `arguments` parameter to specify the profiles (yet I haven't tried this). See [here](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html). If you need different profiles during the release run you might need to provide separate configuration for the different goals.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Preparation Goals Documentation](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#preparationGoals), notably "*Space delimited.*" Here, the term *"-Pprofile3,profile4"* is interpreted as yet another goal to execute. Passing custom arguments is not supported in that place. Also note that clean & verify are already run during *release:prepare*, so you would run them twice.

From the comments below your questions; As you already have a plugin for your desired task(s), make that plugin run directly as a preparation goal.